# How to call a function inside constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following class:

```
class QuestionService {
   static $inject = [
      "$interval",
      "$http",
      "$state"
   ];
   constructor(
      private $interval,
      private $http: ng.IHttpService,
      private $state
   ) {

      $interval(function () {
         this.putTestQuestionResponses()  // <-- error here 
                                          // this.putTestQuestionResponse
                                          // is not a function
      }, 5 * 1000);
   }

   putTestQuestionResponses = () => {
      // do something
   };
}
```

What I wanted to do is call the putTestQuestionResponses() inside the $interval function above.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Can someone let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we need arrow function, which will keep the context for us:

```
// instead of this
//$interval(function () { // this will be ... not expected
// we need arrow function
$interval(() => {         // arrow functions keep 'this' related to local context
     this.putTestQuestionResponses() 
}, 5 * 1000);
```

see this for more info:

#### [TypeScript Arrow Function Tutorial](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/arrow-function-typescript-tutorial/)

or here:

#### [Arrow Functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) by [Basarat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat)